# Moving to next cell in another document

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

While working in `Range` of another document `TCN.docx` I am getting Error of `method or data member not found` on `rng.MoveRight unit:=Cell` position.

```
Sub TNC()
Dim odoc As Document
Dim rng As Word.Range

    Set odoc = Documents.Open(filename:="C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\TCN.docx", Visible:=True)
    Set rng = odoc.Content
    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    rng.Find.Font.Bold = True
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "BU"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
    End With
        rng.Find.Execute
        If rng.Find.Found = True Then

        rng.MoveRight unit:=Cell  **ERROR position**
        rng.COPY
    Else
    End If

odoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)

End Sub
```

for better understanding

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited: after question editing by Cindy Meister

`MoveRight` is not a valid method for `Range` object while it is for `Selection` object

and there's no `Cell` value for `unit` enumeration, while `wdCell` is

to copy the element one cell to the right of the found one, use

```
    ...
    rng.Find.Execute
    If rng.Find.Found = True Then
        rng.Select
        Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCell
        Selection.Copy
    Else
    End If
    ...
```